# Customise size of data points , height and width in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

Can you customise the height and width of the data points on Scatter chart? I want the square data point to be long rectangle line as demonstrated on the image below. The only option I see is pointRadius but that increases both h/w so doesn't give me desired size.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score -1):

On options of chart.js, adjust `barPercentage` of `xAxes`

Comment: `barPercentage` won't have any effect on points.